# folder content doesn't get refreshed automatically in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, files, directory

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and when I'm doing experiments which creates new files inside a particular folder X. But I can't see these new files inside X without refreshing X.

I have increased the count to 1M in

```
/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

but still the issue is not fixed.

How to fix it?

**EDIT**
As suggested, output of `cat /etc/xdg/autostart/user-dirs-update-gtk.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update
Name=User folders update
Comment=Update common folders names to match current locale
Terminal=false
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;LXDE;Unity;
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
X-KDE-autostart-after=panel
NoDisplay=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=xdg-user-dirs-gtk
```

Answer (score 7):

The changes are not permanent, therefore

1. Edit the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
   ```
2. Add the line below, eg

   ```
   fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1000000
   ```
3. Reload the changes

   ```
   sudo sysctl -p
   ```

   You should see something like this

   ```
   fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 1000000
   ```

   and with `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

   ```
   1000000
   ```

Comment: Thanks A.B This actually worked for my ubuntu 16.04.2 lts nautilus