# folder not shown when being created by command line

Tags: command-line, directory, ls, mkdir

I have an issue when I am creating a folder by command line. I create it by typing:

```
mkdir TEST
```

and it does not appear on the graphical desktop view. But if I type the command "ls" in the Terminal I can see it.

Also if I create another folder from the graphical view it appears.

And once the folder is created by command line if I try to create it again by graphical view it tells me that this folder already exists.

Also typing <kbd>CTR</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> it does not appear.

If I create the same folder in another location by command line as before, it appears so I do not know what's going on...

Both locations have the same file permissions.

Any clues? Thanks in advance

Comment: The graphical desktop view (I assume you mean `nautilus`, the file viewer) does not always refresh immediately. Press F5 to refresh manually. Does that make a difference?

Comment: After pushing F5 several times it finally appeared!!! Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @jos Kindly write that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The graphical desktop view (I assume you mean `nautilus`, the file viewer) does not always refresh immediately. Press F5 to refresh manually.

You may also want to experiment with the `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` settings as explained in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665521/folder-content-doesnt-get-refreshed-automatically-in-ubuntu-14-04). The default is 8192, you can easily raise that to 1000000.

`inotify` is the mechanism that is triggered whenever something in the file system changes, as happens when you create a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the file as root in the root home / and checking the folder as a unprivileged user in home/username/?

Type $pwd in the folder from terminal and see where you are in the filesystem and maybe ls -l in terminal and see who who owns the folder and what the folder permissions are.

Comment: I created the folder in another hard disk having root privileges. Anyway after pressing F5 several times it appeared :)

Comment: Looks like you're sorted then :)

Answer (score 0):

The GUI is slow and it reflects changes only on refresh.

Any command executed successfully from the terminal will always apply, its just the GUI which maybe a little slow to reflect it as a refresh of the view is to be triggered to get the newest entries.

Comment: This was already explained by others