# Nautilus does not auto refresh after creating new files in directory

Tags: command-line, python, nautilus, filesystem, directory

I have a python program that creates some .csv files in the same directory as the python script. I navigate the directory containing the script in nautilus and then run the program. The new files do not show up in the open nautilus window after the program ends. I have to press F5 to "refresh" the nautilus window for the new file to be listed in the directory. Is there any way I can have this happen automatically? Is this a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

It's the normal behaviour of nautilus.

It can be overcome by editing the file /etc/sysctl.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

and add the line below to the file:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1000000
```

after which you should reload the changes

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

You should then see something on the lines of

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 1000000
```

and with `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

```
1000000
```

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665521/folder-content-doesnt-get-refreshed-automatically-in-ubuntu-14-04) Originally an answer for v14.04 but also works on later versions.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make nautilus auto update.