# Newly created files not showing up in Nautilus window

Tags: nautilus

I have a Nautilus window open for a dir.   I create a new file in a terminal window in that dir.  but when you view the nautilus window, the file does not appear.  Instead, to see the newly created file in nautilus, i have to exit the dir and then re-enter, and now it shows up.

so it is like Nautilus is a static view of the dir, which doesn't make sense to me.
shouldn't the window dynamically reflect the list of files in that dir?
or if it doesn't, is there some better way to get the updated dir listing rather than this cumbersome exit/re-enter process that I follow?

Iam running Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162990/nautilus-does-not-auto-refresh-after-creating-new-files-in-directory

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour of Files, aka nautilus, is probably implemented like this for performance reasons. Rather than exiting nautilus and reloading it, press either <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to refresh the display.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162990/nautilus-does-not-auto-refresh-after-creating-new-files-in-directory) suggests you could change the behavior by changing a system setting.

Comment: thanks for that answer.   i can appreciate the default behaviour in cases where one is working on a dir at a time manipulating files.   the technique with to function/cntl keys is just what i needed.    i appreciate the help

Comment: Please "accept" the answer (check the green mark) if this answer helped you, for reference of future users.